# Can not load CSS in Django

Tags: css, django

I'm new to Django and now I have problem with loading css files.
I have this directory tree in my windows system:

case 1:

```
.
|__myproject
      |__+myproject
      |__+myapp
      |__-static
      |      |__-css
      |           |__style.css
      |__-templates
              |__base.html
```

base.html =>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"  type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    # ...
  </body>
</html>
```

settings.py =>

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATICFILES_DIR,
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # ...
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # ...
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        # ...
    },
]
```

with those settings and configurations, CSS file can not be loaded.

But when I change my directory tree to this:

case 2:

```
.
|__+myproject
|__+myapp
      |__-static
      |      |__style.css
      |__-templates
             |__base.html
```

and base.html =>

```
# ...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}"  type="text/css">
# ...
```

Now it is working.

So what is the problem with case 1? What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please add these lines in your settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

Comment: Not working. your settings returns this error: ?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

Answer (score 0):

You have written some inconvenient coding.

1. `<!DOCTYPE html>` should be the first line. Then `{% load static %}`

2.Use different types of quotes. (" " and ' ') for href and static.

3.use type="text/css" in link. like this-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"  type="text/css">
```

*In your code computer things ("{% static ") and (" %}") are two separate strings,
so `style.css` gets out of syntax. For this particular situation (quotes inside quotes)
python supports both (" ") and (' ') (see color of text) *

I hope that helps.Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed the points you mentioned and edited my code and question but the problem still exists.

Comment: Then try some few silly things like putting style.css directly inside static folder rather than static/css/style.css,,  or  writing staticfiles_dirs directly like- STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),].it may help you to identify your problem.